# What is the advantage of adding $\log$ Barrier to solve a Linear program?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$,  $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. Let $Ax \leq b$ be the set of linear inequalities which can be written as $a_i^Tx-b_i \leq 0 \,\,\,\,\forall i= 1, \ldots , m$. Consider the following linear program

$$
\min_{Ax\ \leq\ b} c^Tx \tag{1}     
$$
where $c \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is an arbitrary vector. If this problem has a solution, then according to representation theorem (or Weyl-Minkowski) the solution happens at vertices of the constraint set.
[Convex optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) on page 499 says $f(x)=-\sum_{i=1}^m \log (b_i -a_i^Tx)$ is a self-concordant $\log$ barrier function for linear inequalities. So, the above constraint problem can be an unconstraint problem as
$$
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{m}} c^Tx -\sum_{i=1}^m \log (b_i -a_i^Tx) \tag{2}
$$

Let the solutions of (1) and (2) be $x_1^\ast$ and $x_2^\ast$ respectively.

1- Are the solutions the same ($x_1^\ast=x_2^\ast$)? (I mean, Barrier bans the algorithm to approach to the boundary of the constraint set because it goes to infinity. However, the solution is on the boundary. How can (2) catch the solution?)
2- In terms of iterations and algorithm complexity which one is superior? I know for (2) we can use Newton's method to find the answer but how using Newton's method accelerate the algorithm?

3- Can we analytically show that the two problems are the same or one has superiority to the other?

Please address my questions carefully by providing rigorous proofs.

Comment: Ah, thanks, yes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, the solutions are not the same. On p. 499, the book is merely presenting an example of a self-concordant function.
2. When you ask about algorithm complexity for problem (1), which algorithm do you have in mind? At this point in the book's development, it is not clear how to solve problem (1) efficiently. The book will present a strategy that utilizes log-barrier functions in chapter 11.
3. No, the problems are not equivalent.

You should read chapter 11 (Interior-point methods), and specifically section 11.2, which presents a strategy to minimize $f_0(x)$ subject to the constraints $f_i(x) \leq 0, Ax = b$ by solving a **sequence of subproblems** of the form
\begin{align}
\text{minimize} & \quad f_0(x) + \sum_{i=1}^m - (1/t) \log(-f_i(x)) \\
\text{subject to} &\quad Ax = b
\end{align}
with increasing values of $t$. Newton's method is used to solve each subproblem. As $t$ increases, the solution of the subproblem  becomes a better approximation to the solution of the original problem. That is how log-barrier functions are used to solve problems with inequality constraints.

Comment: I appreciate for your patience but I am little bit confused. Linear program is a convex problem so it can be solved using interior point method? Is it true? I have the following questions to understand my question better. Are these solutions close, i.e. $x_1^{\ast}$ and $x_2^{\ast}$? Can (2) be seen as the subproblem of (1) which gives an approximate solution? How many subproblem we need to define to solve (1) using interior point method? What is the optimal value of $t$ for getting a close solution to $x_1^{\ast}$?

Comment: Yes, a linear program is a convex problem, and a linear program can be solved using an interior point method. In fact, interior point methods often give state of the art performance for solving LPs. Interior point methods were originally developed for linear programming problems, and only later were extended to more general convex problems.

Comment: No, the solution to problem (2) is not necessarily very close to the solution to problem 1. **However**, if you had written problem (2) as minimizing $c^T x - (1/t) \sum_{I=1}^m \log(b_i - a_i^T x)$, then we could say that if $t$ is large then the solution to problem (2) is close to the solution to problem (1).

Comment: When the factor of $1/t$ is included, and $t$ is large, then the solution to (2) gives a good approximation to the solution of (1). Regarding how many subproblems you need to solve, and how large $t$ needs to be, I would say just read chapter 11 for more info about that.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: littleO: What is the most efficient algorithm that solves LP? Is there any or depending on the problem it differs?

Comment: For small or medium-sized LPs interior point methods are state of the art. Interior point methods are a highly developed topic, so the best and most sophisticated interior point methods are a little more complicated than what is described in Boyd and Vandenberghe. Vandenberghe's 236c notes are one good resource for learning about more sophisticated interior point methods. For huge linear programs, interior point methods might no longer be useful because solving the KKT system at each iteration may be too expensive. For such problems, first-order methods might be used instead.

Comment: The Mosek software package has very good interior point method implementations.

Comment: Vandenberghe's 236c does not have a specific subject on interior point methods http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236c.html. could you tell me which one you meant?

Comment: Chapters 15 - 19 develop sophisticated interior point methods. The culmination is chapter 19 on primal-dual interior point methods. Most people don't need to understand interior point methods in such detail; you can probably just understand the simpler versions that are given in the Convex Optimization textbook, and use a software package such as Mosek to solve any linear programs that you need to solve.